# How to correctly define a reference (React.RefObject<StyledComponentClass>) for styled-components (for TypeScript)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

How to correctly define a reference for styled-components?

I wrote the following test code. This is a refined code, unlike the previous one ([How to correctly define a reference (React.RefObject) for styled-components (for TypeScript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53103497/how-to-correctly-define-a-reference-react-refobject-for-styled-components-for)). Added reference type `StyledComponentClass< {}, any>`.

```
import React, {Component, RefObject, ReactNode} from 'react';
import styled, {StyledComponentClass} from 'styled-components';

type TModalShadowContainer = StyledComponentClass<{}, any>;

const ModalShadowContainer: TModalShadowContainer = styled.div` 
    background-color: black;
`;

export default class Modal extends Component {

    private readonly modalRef: RefObject<TModalShadowContainer>;

    constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props);
        this.modalRef = React.createRef<TModalShadowContainer>();
    }

    public render(): ReactNode {
        return (
            <ModalShadowContainer ref={this.modalRef}>
                {this.props.children}
            </ModalShadowContainer>
        );
    }

}
```

The error appears on the line:

```
<ModalShadowContainer ref={this.modalRef}>
```

Error text:

```
Type 'RefObject<StyledComponentClass<{}, {}, {}>>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: Component<{ as?: string | ComponentClass<any, any> | StatelessComponent<any> | undefined; theme?: {} | undefined; }, any, any> | null) => any) | RefObject<Component<{ ...; }, any, any>> | undefined'.
  Type 'RefObject<StyledComponentClass<{}, {}, {}>>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<Component<{ as?: string | ComponentClass<any, any> | StatelessComponent<any> | undefined; theme?: {} | undefined; }, any, any>>'.
    Type 'StyledComponentClass<{}, {}, {}>' is not assignable to type 'Component<{ as?: string | ComponentClass<any, any> | StatelessComponent<any> | undefined; theme?: {} | undefined; }, any, any>'.
      Property 'setState' is missing in type 'StyledComponentClass<{}, {}, {}>'.
```

How to describe (define) a ref in TypeScript lang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps.

```
type MamkinHackerType<T> = T extends StyledComponentClass<React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<infer ElementType>, infer ElementType>, infer T, infer H>
  ? ElementType & React.Component<React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<ElementType>, ElementType> & T & H>
  : never
;

private readonly modalRef = React.createRef<MamkinHackerType<typeof ModalShadowContainer>>();
```

Comment: Where did you find this solution?

Comment: Just see the type what want to get ts-compiler and "infer" it with TypeScript conditional types.

Comment: But I think it is not a good solution. We need general improvements in react/styled-componets typings.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Для меня это пока высший полет)